# Download button for model data in django admin panel

Tags: python, django, menu, django-admin, admin

I'm not sure, but this should be simple. Confusingly, googling for the ways doesn't seem to return clear and concise answers.

I shouldn't need to change any forms. All I want is a custom action in the model page where all the data is listed. This button should allow me to download the table as a .csv file for example.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You need Django import export.

https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export

Specifically this section.

https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#admin-integration